# Correcting p-values when accounting for age and sex in a study where the main objective is to find differences between disease/control

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, small-sample, univariate

So I analyzed my metabolomics data using Mann Whitney U tests and OPLS-DA. My data is super small, with the control group only having 5 samples and the other groups having 10 and 14 samples respectively. Now I am being asked to find out if age, sex or medication have an effect on the differenced I saw. Should I redo the same procedure for age, sex, and medication? Would I then have to adjust p-values even more?

Comment: "Would I then have to adjust p-values even more?" It's arguably better doing it than not doing it; if you don't, obviously you have a higher than nominal probability for random meaningless significances as always in multiple testing problems. That said, which such small sample sizes testing in multivariate settings normally doesn't make much sense anyway. You'll have to live with the fact that small samples don't give you strong information.